# How to send a Ruby hash object with objects as keys to front end Javascript as a Map object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

Javascript doesn't support having objects as object keys, but the Map object does. My question is, is there a way to easily send such an object from back end to front end?

```
def test_controller
  object = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2}
  front_end_object = {object => 5}
  render json: front_end_object, status: 200
end

$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "/pull_from_test_controller",
  dataType:"json",
  contentType:"application/json",
  data: {},
  success: function(response, status_string, jqxhr) {
     console.log(response)
  }
})
```

The `response` that's logged in front end, as expected, since it was converted to JSON, has the `object` built in the backend as a string key.

```
// console response
response = {{"a"=>"1","b"=>"2"}: 5}
// further inspection
Object.keys(response)[0] = "{\"a\"=>\"1\", \"b\"=>\"2\"}"
```

Is there some way to easily convert this in front end to a Map object to again have an object as a key, or perhaps in the rendering process indicate this?

My current solution is just to JSON.parse, but this seems clunky

```
JSON.parse(Object.keys(response)[0])
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality (linked from `Map`) - objects won't be equal if I understand it correctly. A possible workaround could be using stringified objects as keys.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly noticed that in JS, object keys should be strings. So why not simply use strings?

```
# In Ruby
def test_controller
  object = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2}
  front_end_object = {"key"=>object, "value"=>5}   # Look here
  render json: front_end_object, status: 200
end
```

```
// In JS
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "/pull_from_test_controller",
  dataType:"json",
  contentType:"application/json",
  data: {},
  success: function(response, status_string, jqxhr) {
     console.log(response)
     // Should be: {"key":{"a":1,"b":2},"value":5}

     // Then no need to parse or anything, just access the values directly.

     console.log(response.key)     // {"a":1,"b":2}
     console.log(response.key.a)   // 1
     console.log(response.key.b)   // 2
     console.log(response.value)   // 5
     
  }
})
```

I suggest you use some more meaningful names than `key` and `value` ;)